# How to interact with database file by c++

Tags: c++, mysql

I am new to database programming.
I am trying to make an application that interacts with a database file locally so that I can use those database query.

I tried to use mySQL connection c++ 1.1.6, and run [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/en/connector-cpp-examples-complete-example-1.html) example.

Following error is what I get:

```
MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' <10061> <MySQL error code: 2003, SQLState:>
```

I guess that I need to have a server on for connecting. What I want is just an interaction with a database file locally, do I need to make this connection also? If I really need this connection, how to make it works?

Comment: You need a server that run MYSQL.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any library that do not need another server running but still can manipulate a database file?

Comment: Most database requires a server. Probably you should try SQLite

Comment: Thank you, I will try it. Btw, why database always requires a server? I mean, they are just a file with tables, with a library containing parser, I should able to manipulate the database, am I right?

Comment: No, you are not correct.  A MySQL database does not exist in a single file.  If you believe you have such a file, you are likely to be incorrect.